# Magento2: Filter ProductCollection by Product Type (type_id)

Tags: magento2, filter, product-collection

I have the following in my custom module helper:

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection,
  array $data = []
) {
  $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
  parent::__construct($context);
}
```

and use the following method:

```
/**
 * Get the product collection filtered by field
 *
 * @param $field
 * @param $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function getProductCollection($field, $value)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollection->load();
    $collection->addFilter($field, $value);
    return $collection;
}
```

In my controller I call the method as such to get all products of type 'simple':

```
$products = $this->dataHelper->getProductCollection('type_id', 'simple');
```

However, this doesn't work as it gives me all products, no matter what type.

I can get the type when I use:

```
$products->getTypeId();
```

How do I correctly filter my collection my type_id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please, remove `load()` from the line `$this->_productCollection->load();`, because you can not filter the collections that has already been loaded.